# Serializer in patch method does not check fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am trying to partially update a model and overwriting the patch method. It works fine when I send correct data, but my problem is, that when I send **incorrect** data the serializer stays `True` and I still get a 200 status code and nothing gets updated. With incorrect data I mean wrong field names. I could basically send any field name and get a 200 status code. So I think the fields are not checked by the serializer...

```
class BuildingUpdateAPI(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = BuildingSerializer

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Patches building."""

        building = buildings.get(name=self.kwargs['name_building'])
        serializer = BuildingSerializer(building, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(status=200, data=serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(status=400, data="Wrong data provided")
```

serializer:

```
class BuildingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for Buildings."""

    class Meta:
        model = Building
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
            "...",
            .....
```

Now I am wondering if this is like this by design or if I am doing something wrong in my view. I thought I could overwrite the `validate`-method in the serializer but my model has quite a lot of fields... So I would have to check every field single field which is not optimal I think. Or is there a way to do this somehow elegantly?

I am patching like this:

```
result = requests.request("patch", url=endpoint, json=payload, headers=get_headers())
```

Comment: `patch(...)`? shouldn't it be `partial_update(...)`?

Comment: Thanks Arakkal, I am not sure if it should. If I change it to `partial_update(...)` it works the same but the problem remains.